# Issue while building a new job in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

Hi guys i am facing a problem when trying to build a new job in Jenkins it says:

SyntaxsError: Invalid regular expression:/^[/: Unterminated character class
(form not submitted)

please do you know what is the problem?

Comment: What is your regular expression?

Comment: this message is appears when i name my job and press OK

Comment: Are you facing this issue even while triggering an existing job?

Comment: actually i faced this problem when i used chrome and IE but i changed to Firefox and it works fine. What is the problem do you think?

Answer (score 1):

Are you the admin of this Jenkins server, or just a user? It seems like the admin enabled Project Naming Restrictions, but entered a bad RegEx